# I changed a primitive mesh, need to restore it to defaults.

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, 3d-view

Brand new to blender, just finished the doughnut tutorial. Next project to teach myself is I'm trying to make a cupcake on my own.

Not sure what I did, but I needed a hollowed out cylinder. So I made a new cylinder. Maybe I used an ngon setting not sure. I changed the properties of it to make it not have face ends so it'd be hollow. Now every time I make a cylinder (shift a) it creates this face end missing cylinder, I also don't get the tool to change the number of starting vertices, etc.

How can I restore my blender primitive settings? So when I make a new cylinder primitive its the same type of cylinder if I were to start a whole new project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you add a new primitive object you get this little window (if it's closed, click on the + icon), in which you can set all preferences.

The window disappears after you perform any operation.

[image]

In the file menu you have also the option "Load factory settings" to restore all preference changes to their default value.

Comment: Thank you I totally missed the "+" symbol. I must of closed it accidentally. I just loaded up blender to try the load factory settings. When I made a new shape it was restored so a reboot fixed it oddly enough. But the factory settings is a good thing to know.